# My delegate type isn't working "Method name expected"

Tags: c#, delegates

I tried this:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int add(int x, int y);
    public class ff
    {
        public static int addNumbers(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public static int substractNumbers(int x, int y)
        {
            return x - y;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Delegate delegare = new add(ff.addNumbers);
             Console.WriteLine(delegare(3,4));
        }
}
```

I don't see why I'm getting this error"Method name expected".
When I use a delegate with a void function it works.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of your `delegare` variable is just `Delegate`. That could refer to *any* delegate. In order to invoke a delegate (in the normal way), you should have an expression of the appropriate type.

After fixing the naming conventions and removing the unnecessary nested class - and demonstrating a method group conversion - your code looks like this:

```
using System;

public delegate int Int32Operation(int x, int y);

class Program
{
    public static int AddNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public static int SubtractNumbers(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int32Operation op = new Int32Operation(AddNumbers);
        Console.WriteLine(op(3, 4)); // Prints 7

        op = SubtractNumbers; // Method group conversion

        Console.WriteLine(op(3, 4)); // Prints -1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out:

```
add delegare = new add(ff.addNumbers);
```

The type of your delegate should be `add` since you defined so.